# TextFormField: manipulate initial Value when using Controller

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, textfield, textformfield

I have a TextFormField where I use a controller to show a date. This is the code snippet:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
...
child: TextFormField(
            controller: widget.controllerDate,
            onTap: () => Dialogs.showSheet(context,
                child: buildDatePicker(), onClicked: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.controllerDate.text = dateTime.toIso8601String();
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }),
            readOnly: true,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Day',
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
```

The Problem is that I dont want to show the complete value the controller holds. Insteat I want to convert the date to a specific format but I dont know how manipulate the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert DayTime to a specific string format using the Dart [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) library.

```
var formattedDate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateTime.now());
```

You can then assign this string to your controller text for the TextFormField.

By the way, I don't believe you can change the value of widget.controllerDate as it is a final field! I recommend you create a TextEditingController variable in the build method of your widget and use that as the controller of your TextFormField, and update its value and the widget using setState.

I hope this helps you!